# PDF print on a edit form - APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I've followed [this](http://www.apex-reports.com/order.html) tutorial but when I tested it doesn't work.

I've created a "Form on a Table with Report", and tried to put a button on the edit page and set its action as "Download printable Report Query" and linked it to my own Report Query.

That's the info. about the branch:

[image]

I've being struggling all week, but couldn't find anything, thanks in advance.

General Information:

Oracle 11g
Application Express 4.2.5
Apex Listener 2.0.5
Glassfish 4.0

Comment: What you're asking is of a tall order. This is a paid-for product for a very, very niche market. Provide more info about your setup, like what printserver option did you go with. Any errors whatsoever anywhere? Either way, you may be best served picking this up with the vendor. They provide free support for 6 months after purchase, which should land you a lot more success than no or random guesses here...

Answer (score 0):

I would start by first confirming that you can output a default format pdf report from a classic report.  This is the easiest case and will help to show where you might have a set up problem.

Follow these two guides:
[Custom PDF Reports](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/learnmore/custom-pdf-reports-1953918.pdf)   -- especially the sections on Configuring APEX Listener as a Print Server and Printing a Simple Classic Report as PDF

[PDF Printing Tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r42/PDF_Printing_oll/PDF_Printing_oll.html?cid=8191&ssid=11547656049978)

Once you get this working, you can expand out to making your own custom xsl-fo template file and making your own print button and you will have a better idea of where problems are arising in the process.

Comment: Yes Jase, I can generate PDF, the problem is that when I put a button on a edit page, the button instead of downloading the pdf, submits the form.

Comment: Changing the URL directly just works when the query doesn't needs a parameter.

Comment: Could you show me an example of the url that is working and how you are passing a parameter when it doesn't work?